# Run terminal sudo command at startup

Tags: scripts, root

I need to run the following command at startup or upon login to make my samba share accessible to my file system. How can I make this command run when I start my computer?

```
sudo smbnetfs ~/Shared -o allow_other
```

Note that this command requires `sudo` and must be run from a terminal. Putting it in startup applications does not work.

Comment: Configure sudo to allow you to run that command , smbnetfs, to run without a password. Better, what are you doing exactly ? More likely than not there is a better configuration option. https://superuser.com/questions/262778/set-proper-rights-for-sshfs-mountpoint-so-it-can-be-shared-with-samba

Comment: All I am trying to do is fuse my samba share with my filesystem so apps like Thunderbird and Firefox can browse the samba drive. If I run the sudo smbnetfs ~/Shared -o allow_other command it works perfectly but I have to run it every time I reboot. I'd like to automate this at startup.

Comment: Try editing `/etc/fuse.conf` to include the option allow_other see http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/mount.fuse.8.html . But how and what user is mounting samba ? should not need to do this.

Comment: The samba share is mounted by Gigolo at startup. That part works flawlessly. The smbnetfs command is to allow the samba share to become part of my filesystem so it is accessible to browse by all applications. All I need to do is get that command to run at startup.

Comment: startup or login ? As I said, once you determine what options you want via the command line, the next step is to then edit the appropriate config file, in this case, I believe it is `/etc/fuse.conf` and done. If you want it at startup, try putting it in /etc/rc.local or write a boot script. If you want it at login, configure sudo to allow you to run that command without a password.

Comment: why not add the share to /etc/fstab ??  I primarily rely on NFS; but I mount my [home] NAS (samba only) backup devices via /etc/fstab  (most are ,user so they're not always mounted; but i've had them ,auto before)

Comment: Would adding it to /etc/rc.local do the job?

Comment: Yes, rc.local was the solution. The reason it didn't work when I tried it earlier is that I needed to make it executable. I solved that issue by running sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local and now it is working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @guiverc - frustrated user who just wanted to do things the hard way and not bother with proper configuration.

Answer (score 32):

Create a file: `/etc/rc.local`

File contents:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
smbnetfs /home/user/Shared -o allow_other
exit 0
```

Save the file and make it executable with this command:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local
```

The commands in the file before `exit 0` will be run as root at startup.

Comment: idk why it doesn't work in Lubuntu 18.  By running 'systemctl', and going through the details I can see its highlighted:

'rc-local.service loaded failed failed /etc/rc.local'

Comment: is this possible with two sudo commands?