# How can I launch mono application on startup with root rights?

Tags: scripts, sudo, startup, mono

Recently I wrote the program using Mono. This program needs the root rights and I want it launch on startup.

I have Ubuntu 16.04.

I already tried use "/etc/rc.local" (followed [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9853/how-can-i-make-rc-local-run-on-startup) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/956237/run-terminal-sudo-command-at-startup))

/etc/rc.local:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
sudo game_backup.sh "$@" &

exit 0
```

/usr/local/bin/game_backup.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/yahniukov/Documents/programs/my_programs/game_backup
sudo mono ./backup.exe "$@"
```

[Permissions of rc.local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cO1K.png)

Answer (score 3):

Since you are running Ubuntu 16.04 which by default uses `systemd` you should write a `systemd` service unit to control the startup behaviour of your application.

A simple `systemd` unit file looks like as follows, assuming `mono` is at `/usr/bin/mono` since the `ExecStart` line must begin with an absolute path.
Save this in `/etc/systemd/system/my-mono-app.service`.

```
[Unit]
Description=my mono app
# If the service relies on network uncomment the next line.
#After=network.target

[Service]
Type=Simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mono /home/yahniukov/Documents/programs/my_programs/game_backup/backup.exe <your-parameters>

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You have added `"$@"` which implies that there are some parameters passed to your command, so you have to replace `<your-parameters>` with the ones actually used.
You also could use the `systemd` options `Environment` or `EnvironmentFile` to store this. For more information have a look in the man pages `systemd.unit`, `systemd.service` and `systemd.exec`.

After you have created the file, execute the command as follows to tell `systemd` that there was a change.

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Now you should be able to control the service as follows. For a full description see `man systemctl`.

```
systemctl status my-mono-app
systemctl start my-mono-app
systemctl stop my-mono-app
systemctl restart my-mono-app
```

To enable the service as start up, you have to enter the command as follows.

```
systemctl enable my-mono-app
```

Depending on the behavior of your script and application, it might be necessary to change the `Type=simple` part to `oneshot` or `forking`. Not that you have to run `systemctl daemon-reload` after you have made changes to the `my-mono-app.service` file to pick up the changes.

Comment: In addition of Thomas answer, if your app use relative path you should add after ExecStart line : WorkingDirectory={path of your exe}