# $HOSTNAME returns empty in rc.local script

Tags: 18.04, scripts, root, hostname

I'm executing some script on my server startup, using the `rc.local` file (as suggested on [this SQ answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/956539/1039683).

The script sends an email to my address notifiying me that the server has started up.

This is the content of my `/etc/rc.local` file:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh -e
echo "The $HOSTNAME server has started" | mail -s "[$HOSTNAME] start up" me@example.com
exit 0
```

> Obviously, the `me@example.com` is replaced by the correct value in the actual script

The script **does execute at startup** and I receive an email in my inbox, as expected... **BUT!** As the title implies, **the `$HOSTNAME` is not replaced by the actual hostname of my server** ; it's just blank. Here's the details of the email I receive:

```
Subject: [] start up
To: <me@example.com>
X-Mailer: mail (GNU Mailutils 3.4)
Message-Id: <20200131132017.0827D42DA2@example.com>
Date: Fri, 31 Jan 2020 14:20:16 +0100 (CET)
From: root <root@example.com>

The  server has started
```

> Notice the **empty brackets** in the subject, and the space between `The` and `server` on the content.

What I expected, as you might have guessed from the `rc.local` content, was my hostname in the subject and the email content.

I tried executing the same command directly from the terminal, and that worked exactly as expected.

For some reason, when `root` is executing the command through the `rc.local` file on startup, it can not resolve the `$HOSTNAME` variable content and prints nothing instead.

**I tried replacing `$HOSTNAME` by `$(hostname -f)` or even `$(head -n1 /etc/hostname)`**, but the result is exactly the same: no hostname in the received email...

What am I missing here?

---

**EDIT:**

I temporarily hardcoded the value in my `rc.local` script. So the command looks like:

```
echo "The server.example.com server has started" | mail -s "[server.example.com] start up" me@example.com
```

In this case, when the server does reboot, I receive my email as usual, with the content as expected... but the subject is still **"[] start up"**!

How can this be possible considering I hardcoded the value inside the brackets. Does the `[]` notation has a special meaning I am not aware of?

Comment: It's possible that the `systemd-hostnamed.service` hasn't completed at the time that `rc.local` is executed. In any case, it's probably a good time to move away from using `rc.local` as described here [Replacing rc.local in systemd Linux systems](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/replacing-rclocal-systemd)

Comment: I also tried the service way with almost exactly the same steps as described in your link, without success: still no `$HOSTNAME` interpolation.
I thought about the fact that maybe the script was executed before `hostname` was available, but didn't dig more into how to wait for it to be ready before executing my own service. Which I'll do now. If you have any hints, I'll take them!

Comment: What method did you use to obtain the hostname when using the systemd method? I wouldn't be surprised if `$HOSTNAME` is unset regardless - however `$(hostname -f)` should work (at least if you used `WantedBy=multi-user.target` which should be plenty late in the startup process)

Comment: I prefer to use a `@reboot` entry in `root`'s `crontab` for such cases. See: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man5/crontab.5.html

Comment: @steeldriver I used `$(hostname -f)` whith the `systemd` method. And also used `WantedBy=multi-user.target` in my service definition.
But I've found another strange behavior, as explained in my edit.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Would that fix the hostname issue?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8633575/6279345) the problem you're facing is a sudo security policy

try executing your script with the -E flag: `sudo -E startup_mail.sh`

If that does not work try running with the env argument: `sudo -E env "HOSTNAME=$HOSTNAME" ./startup_mail.sh`